# JSON data is not recived by the NodeJS expressJs Server

Tags: jquery, json, node.js, ajax

My ajax request looks like this

```
$.ajax({
    url: baseUrl,
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(sendData),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    success: function (msg) {
        alert(msg);
    }
});
```

where `baseUrl` is a string and `sendData` is the Object to send.

My problem is I don't receive my data in the server as expected. I am using nodeJs in my server (expressJs with body-parser to parse JSON in the request).

But when I use Advanced Rest Client Application from the Chrome store, I get the data as expected. I think my client side code is wrong.

Comment: When inspecting your ajax request in e.g. the chrome dev console, does it send a POST or OPTIONS request? It might be a CORS issue

Comment: Why do you stringify the data and send it?

Comment: with or without stringify. The data is not received on the server

Comment: petul is right. Its using OPTIONS not POST. How can i correct that??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood the problem.

When requesting cross domain resources web browser sends a dummy request with `OPTIONS` as http method to check the server supports cross domain requests. This request is called the "preflight". In my case i was sending a 401 for any request which didn't contain the authKey in the request body. so when Chrome did the first preflight request it got a wrong response. So Chrome didn't try the second request.

I solved the problem by setting the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` 
 as `*` in the response headder whenever the server got an `OPTINS` request.

Answer (score 0):

Usually it's cross domain problem. is the baseURL and the html page are on the same domain?

Comment: No, but i have set the server to respond with allow cross origins

Comment: The chrome Dev console shows its using an OPTIONS request instead of POST. Any idea how to correct that??

Comment: try to use 'method: "POST"' instead of type